# Git - Link other repository to my repository

Tags: git, svn, github

I have some `repo A` and `repo B`. Project in `repo A` depends on project from `repo B`.
I want to do such that when some user try to pull sources from my `repo A`, on pull from `repo A`, sources from `repo B` also must be pulled in some folder. I have see, what SVN can link some SVN repo to other SVN repo.
How can I link git repos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git has [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this.

Example:

```
$ git init repo_a
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/messa/temp/submodule-example/repo_a/.git/
$ git init repo_b
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/messa/temp/submodule-example/repo_b/.git/

$ cd repo_b
$ echo 'This is Project B.' >> README.txt
$ git add README.txt 
$ git commit -am 'Initial commit in B'
[master (root-commit) 5158772] Initial commit in B
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.txt

$ cd ../repo_a
$ echo 'This is Project A, that depends on Project B.' >> README.txt
$ git add README.txt 
$ git commit -am 'Initial commit in A'
[master (root-commit) 7e8275b] Initial commit in A
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README.txt

$ git submodule add ../repo_b project_b
Cloning into 'project_b'...
done.
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .gitmodules
#   new file:   project_b
#
$ git commit -am 'Added submodule project_b'
[master c8fc469] Added submodule project_b
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitmodules
 create mode 160000 project_b

$ tree
.
├── README.txt
└── project_b
    └── README.txt

1 directory, 2 files
```

You can exactly control what commit from repo_b will be linked from repo_a.

For more information, see `git help submodule` or the link above.

But there is one problem - when somebody clones repo_a, the project_b will be there, but empty. After `git clone`, `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` will be needed.

I don't have real-world experience with submodules, but I've seen some criticism - for example [this article](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/). I think it is important to choose the right workflow to avoid most of the problems.